# Pulling names from a string in VBA

Tags: vba

For my code I need to make make strings from a main one that has the following format:

```
NAME_FAMILY_CITY_COUNTRY
```

I need each of those units to be separated to individual strings like:

```
NAME_
FAMILY_
CITY_
COUNTRY
```

As you can see the length of the variables in the original string might differ, I assume I need to use `InStr` with `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT` functions, is that the direction I need to work forward?

Comment: Yes. Or, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Dim x As String
   x = "NAME_FAMILY_CITY_COUNTRY"
   MsgBox Join(Split(x, "_"), vbCrLf) 'split by words separated by "_"
   MsgBox Join(Split(Join(Split(x, "_"), "_|"), "|"), vbCrLf) 'add "_" at the end of each word...
```